# Redirect from PHP depending on POST data

Tags: php, redirect

I am currently looking for a solution to this technical problem: I have an html page that sends a certain data to a php page (fetch) depending on the user. According to this data (let's say 'a', 'b' or 'c') page.php returns the url of the next page: a.html, b.html or c.html. It's easy to get this url with JS on the html page and redirect to the right page but I would like PHP to do the redirection directly without going back to the html page:

```
                                    -> if $_POST['data']=='a' --> a.html
                                   |
page.html fetch(data) --> page.php  -> if $_POST['data']=='b' --> b.html
                                   |
                                    -> if $_POST['data']=='c' --> c.html
```

I have tried several solutions but none of them work. I can't use use PHP header() because I got a lot of lines before, ans serve PHP as JS

```
 <?php
 header("Content-type: text/javascript"); 
 // code here 
 ?>
 <script>let goto='<?php echo $goto; ?>';window.location=goto;</script>
```

I don't know if it is possible or not?

Comment: Look up [`header('Locations: some.php')`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) in the PHP Manual

Comment: If you want to make PHP do the redirection, then there is absolutely NO POINT sending any HTML or anything else to the original page, it will never be seen or actioned as the new page will be sent to the browser, replacing the original